# Vectorized byte-position conversion with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, byte

I have a list of bytes, like so

```
b1 = int(123).to_bytes(length=2, byteorder="little", signed=False)
b2 = int(-987).to_bytes(length=2, byteorder="little", signed=True)

b = b1 + b2

stream = [b] * 10
```

Which you could imagine as an array like

```
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
b'{\x00%\xfc'
```

To convert each position correctly, I would do (knowing which positions are signed, and which are not)

```
for line in stream:
    c1 = int.from_bytes(line[0:2], byteorder="little", signed=False)
    c2 = int.from_bytes(line[2:4], byteorder="little", signed=True)
```

But this is extremely inefficient looping. Given that I know the positions of the "columns", how would I do this with numpy in a column-wise vectorized fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a structured array. So given:

```
In [1]: b1 = int(123).to_bytes(length=2, byteorder="little", signed=False)
   ...: b2 = int(-987).to_bytes(length=2, byteorder="little", signed=True)
   ...:
   ...: b = b1 + b2
   ...:
   ...: stream = [b] * 10

In [2]: for line in stream:
   ...:     c1 = int.from_bytes(line[0:2], byteorder="little", signed=False)
   ...:     c2 = int.from_bytes(line[2:4], byteorder="little", signed=True)
   ...:     print(c1, c2)
   ...:
123 -987
123 -987
123 -987
123 -987
123 -987
123 -987
123 -987
123 -987
123 -987
123 -987
```

Then, create a buffer by joining the bytes, then use the structured dtype with the `numpy.frombuffer` helper:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: buffer = b''.join(stream)

In [5]: arr = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.dtype([('x','<u2'), ('y','<i2')]))

In [6]: arr
Out[6]:
array([(123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987),
       (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987)],
      dtype=[('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<i2')])
```

Note, the names I gave, `'x'`, and `'y'` were just placeholders. Use whatever you want. But with whatever name you choose, you can index into the structured array:

```
In [8]: arr['x']
Out[8]: array([123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123], dtype=uint16)

In [9]: arr['y']
Out[9]:
array([-987, -987, -987, -987, -987, -987, -987, -987, -987, -987],
      dtype=int16)
```

Note, if you don't care about the names, you can use the shorthand dtype spec:

```
In [10]: np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.dtype('<u2,<i2'))
Out[10]:
array([(123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987),
       (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987), (123, -987)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<u2'), ('f1', '<i2')])
```

You can read more about specifying dtypes [in the official docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Comment: Updated my question to take signs into account. Please re-check.

Comment: @komodovaran_ that's substantially different... but maybe with a structured dtype...

Comment: @komodovaran_ ok, updated it to take that into account with structured arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use structured numpy arrays:

```
data = np.zeros(100, dtype=[('a', '<u2'),('b','<i2')])
data['a'] = 123
data['b'] = -987
stream = data.tobytes()

data = np.frombuffer(stream, dtype=[('a', '<u2'),('b','<i2')])
```